# Is it possible for PHP or Ajax to check for changes in a database and display a toast?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, admin, intervals

Is there a way where PHP or Ajax can check if a value in a database has changed from false to true. This is how I plan on making this. There is a Admin Dashboard, if the person has completed a certain task the admin can manually change their achievement status and they receive a toast with the achievement they unlocked.

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but for us to help you need to state your exact problem, show the code you have written so far, and ask questions based on that.

Comment: I don't have any code at this moment. I am currently learning Laravel to redo the projects.